# Calculate the blur level of the overlay image depending on its size, taking into account ranges of values

Tags: image, algorithm, math, image-processing, blur

I'm writing a script that imposes many cliparts (small pictures) on one large image. The dimensions (width) of the overlapping cliparts can be random, for example, "from 20 to 100 pixels". As an additional effect, blur is added for each clipart, the level of which is also indicated in the range, for example, "from 2.00 to 8.00" and applied in a random order. There are no problems with this, everything works fine, the cliparts are added randomly, with a random blur...

Now I want to make it so that "the current size of the clipboart is smaller" (in the program cycle), "the it needs to be blurred more", and it is necessary to take into account the two specified ranges of values: in pixels "from 20 to 100" and blur level "from 2.00 up to 8.00".

For example:

1. If the "width of the clipart" is 100 pixels, then it is needed to apply blur 2 (minimal).
2. If the "width of the clipart" is 20 pixels, then it is needed to apply blur 8 (maximal).

I do not understand how to correctly **calculate the "needed blur"** from 2.00 to 8.00 **for any size of the clipart** from the range of 20 to 100? Please, help me to make this calculation. I do not understand mathematics well and can not find a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was helped to find the answer to this question on the Russian version of this site here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767962/